# How to access a bug's XML page on Bugzilla using python with pycurl?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, bugzilla, pycurl

I am not able to retrieve every information (such as comments, attachments, estimated time...) from a bug on Bugzilla (my version is 4.2.5) using it's Webservice. I have all the IDs of the bugs and am trying to access they're according URL to get the XML format of the bug.

I am told that the Bugzilla API doesn't allow access via cookies. So I have the following but I keep getting stuck at the login page even when providing the correct username and password. Here is what I have so far:

```
pf = {'username' : 'my_username', 'password' : 'my_password' }
fields = urllib.urlencode(pf)
pageContents = StringIO.StringIO()

p = pycurl.Curl()
p.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
p.setopt(pycurl.COOKIEFILE, './cookie_test.txt')
p.setopt(pycurl.COOKIEJAR, './cookie_test.txt')
p.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
p.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, fields)
p.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, pageContents.write)
p.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, True)
p.setopt(pycurl.DEBUGFUNCTION, test)
p.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'https://somewebsite.com/viewXMLof=[ENTER-BUG-ID-HERE]')
p.perform()

p.close() # This is mandatory.

pageContents.seek(0)

for x in pageContents.readlines() :
    print x
```

So what I get displayed is the following:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>    
    <title>Log in to Website</title>
.
.
.
```

This means that I am still at the login page. Any suggestions?

Let me know if further explanation is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bugzilla uses XML-RPC or JSON-RPC. See https://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.4/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService.html and http://xmlrpc.scripting.com/spec

Using XML-RPC you need to POST an XML document to the mybugzilla.com/xmlrpc.cgi URL. Here is an example to get the Bugzilla time information.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
   <methodName>Bugzilla.time</methodName>
   <params>
     <param>
         <struct>
             <member>
                <name>Bugzilla_login</name>
                <value>user@example.com</value>
             </member>
             <member>
                <name>Bugzilla_password</name>
                <value>password</value>
             </member>        
         </struct>
      </param>
    </params>
</methodCall>
```

To get a specific bug use the [Bug.get](https://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.4/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/Bug.html#get) method with a param element like this:

```
<param>
    <struct>
        <member>
            <name>Bugzilla_login</name>
            <value>user@example.com</value>
        </member>
        <member>
            <name>Bugzilla_password</name>
            <value>password</value>
        </member>        

        <member>
            <name>ids</name>
            <value>
                <array>
                    <data>
                        <value>
                            <int>1</int>
                        </value>
                    </data>
                </array>
            </value>
        </member>   
    </struct>
</param>
```

Additionally you can use http://xmlrpc.devzing.com/ to help you test your XML-RPC calls and understand the responces.